# How to create a local ElasticSearch client thats querying a file instead of server?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

As a part of testing my code (python. ElasticSearch) Id like to create an ElasticSearch client that performs any valid query on data from a file (json or whatever) INSTEAD of a server (not even local host).

I tried general direction like so:

```
class LocalTransport(Transport):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        super(LocalTransport, self).__init__(hosts=[{"localhost": "localhost"}])


class LocalElasticsearchClient:
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        local_transport = LocalTransport(input_data)
        self.es = Elasticsearch(transport_class=local_transport)
        # self.es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"host": "localhost", "port": 9200}]). # tried this as well without the transport
        ping = self.es.ping()
        self.index_name = "local_index"
        self.data = input_data
        self.create_index()

    def create_index(self):
        index_mapping = {"mappings": {"properties": {"content": {"type": "text"}, "category": {"type": "keyword"}}}}
        self.es.indices.create(index=self.index_name, body=index_mapping)

        for idx, doc_data in enumerate(self.data):
            self.es.index(index=self.index_name, id=idx, body=doc_data)
```

but it tries to address a local host SERVER instead of creating/working locally.

What Im aiming for is that the query will be performed over a json file (thats loaded to the client or whatever is needed) instead of making any server request.

I must say that im not even sure that it is possible - but ill ask.

If this is not possible or a bad idea - how would you address this problem?

tnx